# Node-Webkit with external module containing native code

Tags: node.js, module, native, node-webkit

I'm using node-webkit with an external module called [edge](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge).

According to the node-webkit docs modules that contain native code must be recompiled using `nw-gyp` as oppose to `node-gyp`. I was able to recompile without error and node-webkit seems to import the module OK.

Heres my code. The code I'm trying to use:

```
var edge = require('edge.node');

var hello = edge.func(function () {/*
async (input) => 
{ 
    return ".NET welcomes " + input.ToString(); 
}
*/});

hello('Node.js', function (error, result) {
if (error) throw error;
console.log(result);
});
```

Which throws the following error when run within node-webkit.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'func'
```

If write the object out to `console.log` I can see:

```
 Object {initializeClrFunc: function}
 initializeClrFunc: function () { [native code] }
 __proto__: Object
```

So the module seems to have loaded. If I run the same code outside of node-webkit, everything works perfectly and I can access the `func` function. This is driving me crazy - and any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: +1 , what you're trying to make sounds very interesting. Edge is _extremely_ experimental technology, you might want to open an issue in their github.

Comment: Yeah - already did that. Really need to try and this to work for a show-case app that I'm building.

Answer (score 0):

`func` method is provided by `edge.js`, the wrapper around `edge.node` native module. So you should replace `require('edge.node')` by `require('edge')`.